# How to fix Prisma Unique Type error when deploying to Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, vercel, trpc

I have the app working directly fine on my local dev env but when deploying to Vercel I got this type error which was not expected.

I'm using Nextjs, Prisma, tRPC.

any hints on what I might be missing?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddXfN.png)

[Vercel deploy log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjtl0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two solutions:

1. Use a prisma `@unique` field (like `id`) to find your unique student:

```js
const student = await prisma.student.findUnique({ where: { id: input.id } })
```

2. Try to find every students with that `input.code` and grab the first one:

```js
const [student] = await prisma.student.findMany({ where: { code: input.code } })
```